# Editing multiple elements in a store of array of objects each with store property

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, state-management, svelte-store

I have an array of objects each with store property. I am able bind a single object in the array to an input field but I am unable to bind all of the objects using an each block. [Here](https://svelte.dev/repl/1681c720bb094a27a070b00fc0a6f7fc?version=3.55.1) is my REPL. I'll also provide code below. Anybody have thoughts on how I can achieve the commented out code (L 24-28)?

The root of the issue seems to be around the fact that:

> Stores must be declared at the top level of the component (this may change in a future version of Svelte)

**How can I use an each block to add input fields for all stores in a list of stores?**

For context, I'd like to have each of the items be it's own store so I can eventually create a custom store that has added logic in the set function.

Thanks!

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/1681c720bb094a27a070b00fc0a6f7fc?version=3.55.1

I have these objects set up.

```
<script>
    const rootStore = writable([
        {name: writable("Hello")},
        {name: writable("World")},
        {name: writable("Worlds")},
    ])

    $: firstName = $rootStore[0].name
    $: allNames = $rootStore.map(item => item.name);
</script>
```

I can add an individual input field for the first name but cannot use an each block to add input fields for each of the names.

```
Edit me:
<input bind:value={$firstName}>

{#each $allNames as name}
    Edit me:
    <input bind:value={$name}>
{/each}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a component that accepts the store as a prop and bind the input value int that component.

Another option is to create an utility that unpacks all the values of the nested stores (and reacts to changes and handles unsubscribes)

```html
{#each $unpacked as name, index}
  <input value={name} on:input={(e) => allNames[index].set(e.target.value)} />
{/each}
```

(But if you can avoid nesting stores, that would be my preference)